# Application.worksheetfunction.sumif with internal arrays as argument

Tags: arrays, excel, vba

I am trying to build a subroutine which checks a certain condition in a client list, separates out the entries which meets the condition, and then average the remaining entries for each name. It is like a doing a pivot table with VBA. I did not want to use the pivot table, since writing the data into a new sheet, refresh it and do something with it adds an unnecessary burden on the speed of the tool. Furthermore, all the arrays are to be kept within the code, rather than written on the sheets. I am almost done with the code, but it is giving me an error in the very end, where I am using the sumif condition. 
**A point of clarification: The argument 'Number' is a global variable declared in the main tool, which comes from the count of names from the main list, which is in sheet5. I hope that the code is self explanatory beyond that.**
What I am getting while running the code is the Error- *Run-time error '1004':
Method 'Range' of object '_Global' failed* on the line `TaskArray(k, 1) = Application.WorksheetFunction.SumIf(Range(Names), NewList(k), Range(ParameterB))`

The Code-

```
Sub Task()

Dim Names() As Variant                                                 'Declare Names 
ReDim Names(0 To Number) As Variant                               'Declare Names as a vector
Dim ParameterA() As Variant                                           'Declare Parameter A
ReDim ParameterA(0 To Number) As Variant                         'Declare Parameter A as a vector
Dim ParameterB() As Variant                                           'Declare Parameter B
ReDim ParameterB(0 To Number) As Variant                         'Declare Parameter B as a vector


Dim i As Integer

For i = 1 To Number

Select Case Sheet5.Range("BO" & i + 1) - Sheet5.Range("BN" & i + 1)
Case 0
Names(i) = ""
ParameterA(i) = Sheet5.Range("BN" & i + 1) - Sheet5.Range("BL" & i + 1)
ParameterB(i) = ""
Case Else
Names(i) = Sheet5.Range("F" & i + 1)
ParameterA(i) = Sheet5.Range("BN" & i + 1) - Sheet5.Range("BL" & i + 1)
ParameterB(i) = Sheet5.Range("BO" & i + 1) - Sheet5.Range("BN" & i + 1)
End Select

Next i


Sheet3.Range("T159") = Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(ParameterA())        'Write the total of Parameter A
Sheet3.Range("T160") = Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(ParameterB())        'Write the total of Parameter B
'________________________ To isolate the list of Names (Unique) with existent Parameter B 
Dim NewList() As Variant

Dim j As Long
Dim d As Scripting.Dictionary
Set d = New Scripting.Dictionary
With d
    For j = LBound(Names) To UBound(Names)
        If IsMissing(Names(j)) = False Then
            .item(Names(j)) = 1
        End If
    Next
    NewList = .Keys
End With
'________________________To create an array of sums of Parameter B
For k = 1 To Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(NewList) - 1
Dim TaskArray() As Variant
ReDim TaskArray(1 To k, 0 To 1) As Variant
ReDim Names(0 To Number) As Variant
ReDim ParameterB(0 To Number) As Variant
TaskArray(k, 0) = NewList(k)
TaskArray(k, 1) = Application.WorksheetFunction.SumIf(Range(Names), NewList(k), Range(ParameterB))
Sheet19.Range("H" & k + 1) = TaskArray(k, 0)
Sheet19.Range("I" & k + 1) = TaskArray(k, 1)
Next k

End Sub
```

Comment: Your ranges appear to be invalid. Your arrays contain either "" or the value of a cell, and I suspect the cells don't contain the names or addresses of ranges.

Comment: Thank you, @Rory, for prompt response. My original arrays- Names() contained either "" or a string value and ParameterB() contained either "" or a double, indeed. However, what I am trying with the TaskArray is to create an auxiliary array with only the unique name list and the sums of their parameterB's. I am getting the first column, that is, the unique names. There are no more blanks in it, and its range is far smaller than the original array's. It is the sumif column which is giving me trouble.

Comment: Those are not ranges, they are arrays. You can't just put `Range()` round them to turn them into ranges. I think you need to rethink your entire approach since SUMIF will only work with ranges on a worksheet.

Comment: I see...Thank you!